# Eclipse Java EE IDE 4.7.2 not work with jdk 9

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed eclipse:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600
```

and I install jdk 9 :

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

I create a java project but it give me errors:

```
package java;

public class JavaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

errors on package,JavaMain,String are :

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

String cannot be resolved to a type
```

java build path like :
[image]

I go to preference -> java -> build path -> classpath variable :
[image]

errors:
[image]

this is my java class path :
[image]

Comment: by the way ,it work well with jdk8. is any additional configuration for jdk9?

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_, try to remove the Java 9 JDK and add again.

Comment: @AntJavaDev Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) comes with full Java 9 support built in.

Comment: @howlger  I get another error while refactoring my package name :java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and java.lang.NullPointerException but refactoring my class name success. Any other configuration needed?

Comment: In the screenshot of the Java Build Path of the project, the JRE modules are missing. Either your Java installation is broken or it is not configured correctly (in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_). If you create a new plain Java project, do you get similar errors? If you switch to a new workspace and create a new plain Java project, do you still get similar errors?

Comment: @howlger thank you ,eclipse work well following your tips.but why eclipse could not find my jre class path?